# How to take backup of ListView in android

Tags: android, listview

Is there any way to take backup of data that we display on ListView. I am populating ListView in android with data form localserver.Taking backup of database at server itself in easy by Exporting that.But i want to take backup of data in app. 
or can i take backup in external disk in android of data form at server

Comment: You can try AsyncTask , when you populate data to listview , meanwhile store the same data to your storage place.

Comment: you can write json/data in text file and save in sd card.

Comment: if the data is not big then you can save it sqlite db.

Answer (score 0):

I handled the above problem.
I am using the `AsyncHttpClient` API in-app.

```
public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response)
```

The third argument response object contains all the data list which I feed to ListView using the adapter.
What I did, was take the response object and parsed it, and save it in a text file.

It worked for me.